# Why might Birdie Jay’s name be destroyed if she makes the statement about Bangladesh?

Tags: plot-explanation, glass-onion-a-knives-out-mystery

In *Glass Onion: A Knives Out Mystery*, there is a scene where a character
named Peg is pleading with Miles not to make Birdie Jay go
through with making a statement to the press about Bangladesh. Peg is worried that
if Birdie Jay makes the statement, her name will be destroyed.

> Peg: Bird showed me the statement you want her to make to the press about Bangladesh,
> and if you make her go through with it, **her name is…destroyed**.

Why might Birdie Jay’s name be destroyed if she makes the statement about Bangladesh?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Birdie Jay is incredibly stupid/naive as she received an email advising her that a factory in Bangladesh was a sweat shop and took no action because of that stupidity.

This is covered in later conversation

> BIRDIE
> An email. With the Sweety Pants
> contractor. Two years ago.
>
> PEG
> reading( )
> "Ms. Jay, wanted to alert you that
> the proposed Bangladesh factory is
> notoriously one of the world's
> biggest sweat shops. Please advise."
> And then you replied... "Sounds
> perfect, thanks!" With your me-moji.
> Dabbing.
>
> Peg is gutted. Then, after a long beat, it dawns on her.
> Very, very slowly:
>
> PEG (cont'd)
> Birdie. Please tell me you didn't
> think "sweat shops"... were where
> they make sweat pants.
>
> BIRDIE
> Miles is going to pay me off. He said
> if I take full responsibility for the
> sweat shops he'll pay me the value of
> my shares, thirty million. I'll do
> what I have to do to save myself.
> He's my only lifeline.

Blanc then accuses Miles of making Birdie take the fall to issue the statement taking responsibility

> BLANC
> Birdie. Bangladesh. Sweetie Pants are
> manufactured there, in a sweat shop.
> You're making Birdie take the fall,
> to cover your ass as the main
> investor.